# mongo db query getsiblingdb ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm able to connect to MongoDB and able to successfully run the below commands

```
mongo -host hostname:port
db.getSiblingDB("$external").auth({ mechanism: "PLAIN",     user: "<username>",     pwd:  "<password>",     digestPassword: false   })
use dbname
db.collectionanme.find({query here})
```

The same commands i tried with ruby but i'm getting error message >> not authorized for query on dbname.collectionname (13)

Below is the ruby code:

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

client = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:port'])
client.with(:auth_mech => :plain, :user => '<user>', :password => '<password>', :digestPassword => false)
db = client.use('dbname')
db[:collectionname].find(query here).each do |doc|
  puts doc
end
```

Here's the error

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/result.rb:214:in `validate!': not authorized for query on dbname.collectionname (13) (Mongo::Error::OperationFailure)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/read/query.rb:62:in `block in execute_message'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:99:in `with_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server/context.rb:63:in `with_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/read/query.rb:61:in `execute_message'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/operation/read/query.rb:55:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection/view.rb:164:in `send_initial_query'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:39:in `each'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to complete the work due to some access issues. but the code looks like below

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

Mongo::Client.new(['hostname:port'], :auth_mech => :plain, :auth_source => :external, :user => 'username', :password => 'password', :digestPassword => false).use('db_name')['collection_name'].find("query").to_a
```